# Windows 11 context menu, file explorer mysteriously revert back to window 10

Tags: windows

I've installed Windows 11 and it's smooth sailing up until some days ago, my context menu and file explorer magically changed into the classic windows 10 style. This is about the time by snip and sketch stopped working, I've made no registry changes whatsoever and would like to revert these back to win11 style and fix my snip and sketch, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `regedit` and check if the following key exists:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2`.

If it exists, export it for backup and then delete the entire key.
This should restore the Windows 11 context menu.

Software that can do it for you the switch back and forth is
[Windows 11 Classic Context Menu](https://www.sordum.org/14479/windows-11-classic-context-menu-v1-1/).

I don't know why Snip & Sketch stopped working. If it's worrying you,
you may check the following (the following links are for Windows 10
so may require some adjustment):

- [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)

Comment: i actually found no registry key like this, and it seems this problem is getting worse as i cant open my photos app aswell

Comment: Do the last two points. See what the first one says before doing the second.

Comment: sfc scannow says it found problems it cant fix

Comment: Then you have no choice but to execute the second point. Backup first any important data.