# Windows 11 photos and snip and sketch suddenly stops opening

Tags: windows

On my windows 11, windows photos and snip and sketch suddenly stop opening, ive made no registry changes, how can i fix this?

Comment: You might take care of your [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1688690/windows-11-context-menu-file-explorer-mysteriously-revert-back-to-window-10).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of the question Harry referenced.  Snip 'n Sketch (Snipping Tool in Windows 11) and Photos work correctly on both my Windows 11 machines. You (OP) were advised to do a Repair Install.